# Bootstrap clear preceding columns when moving to the next line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to organize items in rows of three. When the columns are not the same height however, items that move to the next line end up below previous item, instead of on the left.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        // lot of content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        // little content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        // stays on right side below previous item
    </div>
</div>
```

I have been able to solve this by using JQuery to make all columns with the same y position the same height, but I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a clearfix like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        // lot of content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        // little content
    </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        // now goes to new line
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed this wasn't going to work with "col-sm-6 col-md-4" for example, but I found a solution for that here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Answer (score 0):

you must use `container` class tow show all column within container. then when the column number reach to the 12 column you must use new `row` class to set the new column again directly under previous column.
use this code below

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    // lot of content
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    // lot of content
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    // little content
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    // stays on right side below previous item
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I did before, but I want this to work with multiple classes (e.g. "col-sm-6 col-md-4") as well. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: you don't used `row` class in the last `col-md-4` class. and then my code it is work with every multiple classes without any problem for example you can put `col-sm-4` with `col-md-4` or `col-lg-4` together it is work properly